# How do I receive multipart form data in Azure function?

Tags: python, azure-functions

I want to receive multipart data containing images and texts in Azure Function.

I could see a lot of examples in C# and node[Node link](https://www.builtwithcloud.com/multipart-form-data-processing-via-httptrigger-using-nodejs-azure-functions/) but Could not find anything in python.

Could not find anything in official docs as well [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python)

Comment: Could you make it work?

Comment: after a short research found this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1063#issuecomment-608110162

Comment: @Sidonai No, I didn't find a way to send multipart form data. So, i sent my image as base64 encoded string in json.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have tried the below code and it works for me:

```
import logging
import json
import io
from PIL import Image
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,BlobClient
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.form['name']
    interests =json.dumps(req.form["interests"], indent=2)
    imagefile = req.files["file"]
    filename = imagefile.filename
    filestream = imagefile.stream
    filestream.seek(0)

    blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str= "<your connection string>", container_name="<container name>", blob_name="<blob name>")

    blob.upload_blob(filestream.read(), blob_type="BlockBlob")

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. Created profile with your interests : {interests}. Uploaded your profile image file :{filename} to the blob. This function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

However, you can also use PIL in this case to get the bytes from the image . Then the code looks like :

```
import logging
import json
import io
from PIL import Image
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,BlobClient
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.form['name']
    interests =json.dumps(req.form["interests"], indent=2)
    filename = req.files["file"].filename
    image = Image.open(req.files["file"])
    imgByteIO = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(imgByteIO, format=image.format)
    imgByteArr = imgByteIO.getvalue()

    blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str= "<your connection string>", container_name="<container name>", blob_name="<blob name>")
    blob.upload_blob(imgByteArr)

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. Created profile with your interests : {interests}. Uploaded your profile image file :{filename} to the blob. This function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

Here is the postman request:

[image: Here is the postman request]

Comment: it's not clear: why you get name and interests from req.form and you get file from req.files ? Is it a typo?

Comment: Note, that for some reason this doesn't work without `Content-Length` header. It's set by default with Postman, but not when you send it programmatically.

Comment: Is it required to use `io` to send just a .json file? EX: Send a REST request, get back JSON, create a file **in-memory**, write file to Azure Blob Storage. I can't seem to find ANY examples of how to do this.

Comment: @jayachatterjee-msft:

Opening the file using PIL and `Image.open` rotates the file.